# Why would Google indexing improve without corresponding improvements in Moz domain authority?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index, domain-authority, moz

My website started to be indexed immediately (faster than previously) after any type of content updates in the last 2 weeks.

I interpret this as a rise in its domain authority (DA).  However MOZ's DA number did not change during this period. I think Google increased its credit some way but MOZ didn't count it! Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Coming to point straight, MOZ DA & Ahrefs UR, all these are metrics good to compliment the info from google search console & analytics but not the other way round. Also, they are mostly used to analyze the competitors since we don't have access to their Search Console or GA data.

In my experience, Google analytics & Search console are more credible source to analyze website behavior from a webmaster perspective.
Try looking at user behavior in Google analytics or some new links in Search console.
Also, the recent Core web vitals might be a contributing factor too.